# How to impersonate a user and insert a calendar in its behalf using service account?

Tags: laravel-5, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to create calendars and share them with my organization's users using a service account.
What I would like to obtain is the ability to manage the created calendars both from my website code (using the service account) and from the regular google calendar web interface.
So i thought I could create a dumb user account (with credentials), impersonate it with a service account and then create and share my calendars and manage events both from my weba pp code and google regular user interface.
Is it the right way to proceed? Am I missing something?
If my last guess is right how can I achieve it using laravel and google-api-clients for PHP?

Thank you for your advices

Comment: organization's users are we talking gsuite?

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069432/user-impersonation-with-service-account-using-application-default-credentials)?

Comment: @daimto yes we are talking gsuite organization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Sleeping on it I realized there's no need to impersonate a user and insert a new calendar.
To manage a service account calendar from the officiale web interface you can simply share it with owner rights to the "dumb user"

With something like this:

```
//create calendar
$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary('calendarname');
$calendar->setTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar();
$createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);

//share it with your dumb user 
$rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
$scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();
$scope->setType("user");
$scope->setValue('dumbuser@organization.com');
$rule->setScope($scope);
$rule->setRole("owner");
$createdRule = $service->acl->insert(createdCalendar->getId(), $rule);
```

So my problem is solved for the moment, the only question I'm still thinking about is how can I impersonate a user with service account credential? Well I'll think about it when it will be really useful